# SQL many-to-many select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There are 5 tables

```
books
------
id
name
year

author
------
id
name

store
------
id
name

books_authors
------
id
book_id
author_id

books_stores
------
id
store_id
book_id
```

Every book can have many authors and every book can be in a few stores.
I would like to get book with all its authors and with all stores where it can be found

My code (I use PDO)

```
if(isset($_POST['books'])){
    $books_ids = $_POST["books"];
}

$books_ids_in = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($books_ids), '?'));

$query = "SELECT b.id, b.name, b.year, a.name as author_name, s.name as store_name
          FROM books as b
          LEFT JOIN books_authors as b_a
            ON b.id = b_a.book_id
          LEFT JOIN authors as a
            ON a.id = b_a.author_id
          LEFT JOIN books_stores as b_s
            ON b.id = b_a.book_id
          LEFT JOIN stores as s
            ON s.id = b_s.store_id
          WHERE b.id IN (". $books_ids_in .")
          ORDER BY b.id";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query); 
foreach ($books_ids as $k => $id) {
    $stmt->bindValue(($k+1), $id);
}

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

but in this case I get two string if book has two author (for example) and a lot of string for every store. How can I get one result for every book with all its authors and stores?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT()` over `authors` and `stores`?

Comment: may you give an example, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT
    b.id,
    b.`name`,
    b.`year`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.`name`) AS author_names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.`name`) AS store_names
FROM
    books AS b
    LEFT JOIN books_authors AS b_a ON b.id = b_a.book_id
    LEFT JOIN authors AS a ON a.id = b_a.author_id
    LEFT JOIN books_stores AS b_s ON b.id = b_a.book_id
    LEFT JOIN stores AS s ON s.id = b_s.store_id
WHERE
    b.id IN (". $books_ids_in .")
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` operations have the purpose of generating combinatorial explosions. Your extra rows are the result of such explosions.

You want one row per book, showing authors and stores. Each of these rows contains three kinds of information: book, authors, stores.  So, you need subqueries that can generate exactly one result per book for each type of information. Then you need to join those subqueries together.

It's easy for `books`: you already have a table with one row per.

For `authors` you need this:

```
         SELECT ba.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) author_names
           FROM books_authors ba
           LEFT JOIN authors a ON ba.author_id = a.id
          GROUP BY ba.book_id
```

If you know the authors for a book should be listed in order of id, use `GROUP_CONCAT(a.author_name ORDER BY a.id)`. The order of authors is considered very important by bibliographers and the authors themselves, by the way.

That result set contains rows like

```
  17   James Watson, Francis Crick
  19   Dewey, Cheatham, Howe
```

You do the same sort of thing for your stores.

```
         SELECT bs.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) store_names
           FROM books_stores bs
           LEFT JOIN stores s a ON bs.store_id = s.id
          GROUP BY bs.book_id
```

Then you JOIN your books table to these two subqueries (a/k/a virtual tables) and you have what you want.

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, aa.author_names, ss.store_names
  FROM books b
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT ba.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name) author_names
               FROM books_authors ba
               LEFT JOIN authors a ON ba.author_id = a.id
              GROUP BY ba.book_id
            )  aa ON b.id = aa.book_id
  LEFT JOIN (
             SELECT bs.book_id, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) store_names
               FROM books_stores bs
               LEFT JOIN stores s a ON bs.store_id = s.id
              GROUP BY bs.book_id
            )  ss ON b.id = ss.book_id
```

That will give you

```
  17   The Double Helix   James Watson, Francis Crick   Barnes, Amazon, Harvard Coop
  19   Faking Contracts   Dewey, Cheatham, Howe         Law Bookstore, Amazon
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for such detailed explanation! If I may ask, I use book's ids for search here, and I would like to add some parameter in result to show that, for example, `param = "book"` for every string. Is there any way to do that?